# facebook application - how to send app sugesstion and post directly on user walll

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

how to make application which have the following functions

1 which directly post on user wall when user join the application
2 than he/she sees the page where he/she suggest this application to his/her friends
3 after that he/she sees a page of flash base small game

thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 2):

1. Read the Facebook API. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
2. Use the PHP SDK, or the JavaScript SDK that Facebook provides to do the heavy lifting
3. Start programming
4. Ask SO when you run into more problems.
5. Hire a developer if you don't want to do any of the above! ;-)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: +1, I would add...5) hire a developer if you don't want to do any of the above! ;-)

Comment: Edited to include your suggestion :)